# Encoding GeoJSON to something other than 'UTF-8' from QGIS

Tags: qgis, geojson, encoding, utf-8

I want to save the shp file as GeoJSON and encode it to system,
but my QGIS is disabled for selecting an encoder.

Adjusted the 'ignore shapefile incoding declaration' option, but it did not work.

I want GeoJSON to get Rhino 6. It does not recognize UTF-8. I don't necessarily have to encode to system.

[image]

Comment: I suppose that JSON must use UTF-8 or UTF-16 or it is not valid http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf.

Comment: thanks TomazicM. do you have any idea to solve my problem?

Comment: I don't know Rhino 6, but are you absolutely sure it doesn't support UTF-8? Because that has been around for a very long time. Maybe QGIS writes a BOM (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) and Rhino doesn't like that? If that's the case remove it, for instance in Notepad++.

Comment: oh. Your kindness pleases me. Thank you.
I will try it. :D